# Race condition with INotifyPropertyChanged - c#

Tags: c#, race-condition, inotifypropertychanged

my scenario: There are two comboboxes with a bound `SelectedItem` property. 
The first combobox contains the costcentres and the second one the employees of the selected costcentre.

That means if `SelectedCostcentre` changes, `INotifyPropertyChanged` fires and searches for all employees in the costcentre.

ViewModel:

```
  public abstract class SelectEmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    protected readonly Plant plant;

    public ObservableCollection<Costcentre> Costcentres { get; protected set; }
    public Costcentre SelectedCostcentre { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; protected set; }
    public Employee SelectedEmployee { get; set; }

    public bool CostcentresEnabled
    {
        get { return Costcentres != null && Costcentres.Any(); }
    }
    public bool EmployeesEnabled
    {
        get { return Employees != null && Employees.Any(); }
    }

    protected SelectEmployeeViewModel(Window window, Page page, Plant plant) : base(window, page)
    {
        this.plant = plant;

        PropertyChanged += SelectEmployeeViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        Costcentres = mainController.CostcentreDao.GetByPlant(plant);
    }

    private void SelectEmployeeViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(SelectedCostcentre):
                SetEmployees();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetEmployees()
    {
        if (SelectedCostcentre != null)
            Employees = mainController.EmployeeDao.GetByCostcentre(SelectedCostcentre);
        else
            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
   <ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Costcentres}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCostcentre}"
        DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CostcentresEnabled}"
        Margin="81,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213"/>
    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
        DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
        IsEnabled="{Binding EmployeesEnabled}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213"/>
```

This works great.
Now i build a search function for employees which can find them in all costcentres. If I found one, I need to change the `SelecedCostcentre` and `SelectedEmployee` programatically.

Doesn't this create a race condition? Because If I set the `SelectedCostcentre` property `PropertyChanged` fires and sets the `Employees` property.

```
  private void SetEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        SelectedCostcentre = Costcentres.Single(x => x.Id == employee.Costcentre.Id);
        SelectedEmployee = Employees.Single(x => x.Id == employee.Id);
    }
```

How can I solve this without having a race condition?

Thanks

Comment: race-comndition is the wrong name, this is single threaded. You could have cascading and maybe circular event triggering though. Be clear about what you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no race condition, because the whole thing happens on one thread.

```
SelectedCostcentre = Costcentres.Single(x => x.Id == employee.Costcentre.Id);
```

First setter of `SelectedCostcentre` property is executed, which invokes `PropertyChanged` (in your code I don't see it, but I assume that's just a typo). This in turn calls `SelectEmployeeViewModel_PropertyChanged` handler and `SetEmployees`. So after line above is executed - `Employees` are populated for given selected `Costcenter`, synchronously, without any race conditions.

Comment: oh nice, thank you.
The PropertyChanged is in the ViewModelBase, therefore you can't see it.

Comment: Yes, but I can see `SelectedCostcentre`, and it has default setter (just `set`), while I expected it to do something in that setter to raise property changed event. But maybe you use something like Fody or Postsharp to automatically do that for you.

Comment: I'm using Fody.PropertyChanged. It does create the setter at build time